# How can I fix a prettier problem with unwanted formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

When I save my code, prettier changes the format and it will ruin my code and I don't know how to change it.
and it only occurs when I'm trying to write HTML tags in JS file.

This is my code before saving:

[image: this is my code before saving]

This is my code after saving:

[image: this is my code after saving]

I tried the (command + K , S).
it does work but I want to fix the actual problem.

Comment: Please do not use images and post your code instead! Regarding prettier: do you use `.prettierrc`file for your default formatting?

Comment: [Tutorial](https://blog.yogeshchavan.dev/automatically-format-code-on-file-save-in-visual-studio-code-using-prettier) for *enabling* format on save - I imagine you uncheck the "format on save" thing to disable it.

Comment: You have "babel JavaScript" in the right bottom corner but it should be "jsx" or "JavaScript react"

Answer (score -1):

go to visual studio code settings

search: Print Width

it should be greater or equal 80.

restart IDE

hope it helps